# Kaleidoscope effect using Javascript, CSS or ImageMagick?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, imagemagick

I'm trying to dynamically make a kaleidoscope pattern from a source image.
You can see an example in Flash here: http://www.maegpai.com/mademyshirt/tool/ (click an image to start).

I want to create the same effect using either [HTML Canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/canvas-tutorial/6_1_canvas_composite.html), CSS (masking) or [ImageMagick](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/kaleidoscope/index.php) and PHP.

What would be the best way to create something like this besides Flash?
I'm not concerned about older browsers, if I can get this to work in Safari and Chrome that will be enough.

Comment: Says "page not found"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a CSS one: http://bl.ocks.org/abernier/raw/9070122/ code can be found here: http://bl.ocks.org/abernier/9070122/

Answer (score 0):

If you want it done quickly with the least amount of work on your part, use ImageMagick and PHP, the script is already written for you.

If you want to show off your mad skillz, I'd go for CSS (masking). That seems difficult to me.

If you want to get attention, go with HTML5 Canvas. Everyone thinks it's cool.