# It is possible to create kaleidoscope images generated by php

Tags: php, image-processing

Is this possible. 
My client requires kaleidoscope images to be generated on the site and used and background for butterflies. Hence making them unique.

I found this thread [Kaleidoscope effect using Javascript, CSS or ImageMagick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800945/kaleidoscope-effect-using-javascript-css-or-imagemagick)

But was not much help. The image magic seems to be in Java?? I'm not sure.
It is possible do with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a similar pattern with a voronoi-diagram. It's a dual from the delaunay triangulation. You can animate and paint the voronoi-diagram. You can download my class voronoi-diagram at phpclasses.org.